# Upgrading from 4.6.10 to 4.6.11: upgrade script doesn't run

Tags: upgrade, 4.6.11

When upgrading a D7 site from CiviCRM 4.6.10 to 4.6.11 I run the upgrade script via /civicrm/upgrade?reset=1 and the script isn't running. Instead I'm getting redirected to /user/1

Nothing in the CiviCRM log or the PHP error log. Running on PHP 5.6. The site was a recent clean install using 4.6.10 and I've not noticed any issues up until now.

Where to start debugging this?

Comment: I should have said that I follow the guidance notes at http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Upgrading+CiviCRM+for+Drupal+7 when doing updates

Comment: I have tested this and i am not getting any error at all - so please try again with the same document and if you are getting error please give some screen shot of the error - thanks

Comment: Is it possible for you to do the upgrade with drush with the -v option? 
If so, does it give more info?

Comment: @Ramesh Thanks. I'm getting no errors at all. I point the browser at mybaseurl/civicrm/upgrade?reset=1 and what comes back is mybaseurl/user/1 (which is what I'm logged in as).

Comment: @Catorghans Thanks - I'll give that a try.